# How to filter a table based on a specific column value of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hello I have a table here

```
---------------------
ID | PARTY | Name.Id
---------------------
1  | IND   | 12
2  | IND   | 13
3  | CUST  | 14
4  | CUST  | 15
5  | CUST  | 16
6  | IND   | 17
---------------------
```

I want to return the whole table but filter 'CUST' which has value 15 and 16 in the column 'Name.Id'

The result should look something like this

```
---------------------
ID | PARTY | Name.Id
---------------------
1  | IND   | 12
2  | IND   | 13
3  | CUST  | 14
4  | IND   | 17
---------------------
```

I tried using `where` statement on the 'Name.Id' but it returns only those rows which has a value 15 and 16.

Comment: "rows which have a value 15 and 16" No value is both 15 & 16. Either say "rows which have a value 15 or 16" or say "rows which have a value 15 and rows which have a value 16". (Each suggests a different query.) PS Either say "rows which have" or "every row which has". PS This is an easily found faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask] [help]

Comment: Code questions need a [mre]. Also show what you are able to do.

Answer (score 1):

> whole table but filter 'CUST' which has value 15 and 16 in the column 'Name.Id'

It sounds like you want a where clause like:

```
WHERE NOT (party = 'CUST' and name.id IN(15,16))
```

But CUST seems redundant from your sample data, i.e. you could get away with simplifying it to just `WHERE name.id NOT IN (15,16)`

Comment: Also written as  `party != 'CUST' or name.id not in (15, 16)` which ought to work.

Comment: Not as easy to reason out, in my opinion, which is why I wrote it the way round I did. The OP has said "[except] CUST with Name.id of 15 and 16" which should actually be written as "[except] CUST with Name.id of 15 *OR* 16" - humans make that linguistic mistake all the time - "take all the apples and bananas out of the box" - a fruit cannot be both apple and banana, but we know what it means. Anyway, I digress. While you may appreciate that `not(a = 1 and b = 2)` is equivalent to `a != 1 or b != 2` not everyone is, so I picked the construct that was closest to the natural language expression

Comment: Also, note that `!=` os not standard SQL for inequality; I strive to write standard answers where possible for maximum cross portability

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a whirl?

```
select *
from t
where (PARTY, Name.Id) not in (
     select 'CUST', 15
     union
     select 'CUST', 16
)
```

Comment: Is there a syntax error in this line where (PARTY, NAME.Id)  ?

Comment: It's weird you have that . in the field name.  Try quote it with 'Name.Id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from t
    where Party not in
        (select Party from t
            where Party="CUST" 
                and (Name.Id=15 or Name=16));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is exactly the condition of the task: there must be no records when Party = 'CUSt' and Name.Id = 15 or Name.Id = 16

Answer (score -1):

I think I got the solution here

```
select *
from t
where Party <> 'CUST'
or (Party = 'CUST'
and Name.Id = 14))
```

Comment: Doesn't do "15 or 16".